# GO言語でファイルの読み込み方の違いについて

Tags: go

GO言語を使い、比較的大きなファイル（~100M）を読み込むときに、エラーが発生していまい困っておりました。

Webを参照にして、エラーが発生する箇所は自分で解決できましたが、
なぜ違うfunctionを使うだけで、一方はエラーが出て、もう一方はスムーズにいくのかが理解できず、ここで質問させていただいています。お手数をおかけしますが、下記のプログラムで違いを説明していただけると勉強になり、大変ありがたいです。

```
package main

import (
      "io"
    　"os"
    　"fmt"
      "bufio"
)

func ReadLines01(path string) ([]string, error) {
  file, err := os.Open(path)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  defer file.Close()

  var lines []string
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
  for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
  }
  return lines, scanner.Err()
}


func ReadLines02(path string) []string {
    file, _ := os.Open(path);
    defer file.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(file, 64*1024)

    var lines []string
    for {
        line_byte, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
        a_line := string(line_byte)
        lines = append(lines, a_line)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    return lines
}

func main () {

  fn := "/xxx/thumbnail-000.summary";

  Data01, _ := ReadLines01(fn); //scannerを使った方法
  Data02 := ReadLines02(fn)     //ReadLineを使った方法

  //Data01では初めの数行しか読み込まれませんでしたが、
  //Data02では完全に読み込まれていました。
  fmt.Println(len(Data01), len(Data02)) 
}
```

以前よりscannerを使った方法（ここではReadLine01）を使っており、これまではエラーも発生せず正常に動いていました。上記でも示しましたが、本日、~100Mサイズのテキストファイルを読み込むときに、エラーが発生していました。

具体的には、
テキストファイルの内容は、数字＋文字の羅列です。
横に最大約60000文字ほどあり、縦には3000行ほどです。
（例：324.155969:286.733035 323.959871:286.938968 323.763772:287.144901）
(申し訳ございません、実際にファイルをアップすればよいのですが、ここで、100Mのファイルをアップする方法がわかりませんでしたので、このような方法にしました。)

このファイルを読み込むときに、ReadLine01方式では、上から十数行で結果が返ってきてしまっていました。（例: len(Data01)が12などになります。）

この問題のあるファイルは、別のscriptで作られたものです。
しかし、不思議なことに、別に作成されたファイル（数字は違いますが、同じ内容）ではReadLine01でも完全に読むことができるものもありました。（このようなファイルを１００個ほど作成して、完全に読み込めるものは10個程度でした。）

webで解決方法を探していたところ、NewReaderSizeをみつけましたので、見よう見まねで、functionを作成（ReadLine02方式）してみたところ、上記の100ファイルすべてで、完全に読み込むことができるようになりました。

自分の理解が足りていないだけだと思いますが、
ReadLine01方式のbufio.NewScannerでは、情報をscannerに保持して、それをScanすることで一行ずつ読んでいくと理解しています。また、ReadLine02方式のbufio.NewReaderSize(file, 64*1024)では、ある程度大きなbufferを用意しておいて、reader.ReadLine()でやはり一行ずつ読んでいくと理解しています。

これからだけですと、単純に原因は、Scannerには読み込むときの現在サイズが存在すると思ってしまいます。

質問ですが、
（１）scannerではファイルを読み込むときの限界サイズはあるのでしょうか？
（２）それとも、byteに変換するところが上記の問題の原因なのでしょうか？

自分の不勉強で、皆様の貴重なお時間を割いていただいて大変申し訳ありませんが、
ご教授をお願いします。よろしくお願いいたします。

ちなみにGoのversionは、go1.8.1 linux/amd64です。

Comment: 念のため、一応問題を起こすファイルに関しては、改行コードなど普段は見えないようになっているコードなどもNotepad++を使い一つづつ目で確認していました。しかし、特に原因となるようなものは見当たりませんでした。

Comment: [MaxScanTokenSize](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bufio/scan.go#L69) で一行の最大長が設定されています(64k バイト)。コメントに書かれていますが、`scan.Buffer()` で再設定が可能です。

Comment: @metropolisさん、
ありがとうございます。完全に不勉強でした。やはり最大長を超えていたようですね。scan.Buffer()を使って、1行の長さが長くても対応できるようにscriptを改良します。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaxScanTokenSize の話は既に書かれていますので、別解を。

bufio.Buffer#ReadLine は戻り値の2番目に、「行が長すぎて読み込み途中だったのかどうか」を返します。ですのでこれが false であれば行末を読み込めたという事になります。つまりそこまで文字列を足すループを書けば良いです。

```golang
func ReadLines02(path string) ([]string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    r := bufio.NewReader(file)

    var lines []string

    for {
        var err error
        var line string
        var b []byte

        prefix := true
        for prefix && err == nil {
            b, prefix, err = r.ReadLine()
            line += string(b)
        }
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        lines = append(lines, line)
    }
    return lines, nil
}
```

ちなみに Scanner のデフォルト動作は CRLF の CR を取り除くので、もしこの動作が期待しない物ならば Scanner に渡す splitter を自作するか、上記の様に prefix を判定しながら読む事になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに、"for prefix && err == nil"のようにしておくと、エラーが発生したときに、その行で対処できますね。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。